# How to load content pages async using jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, sitemap, master-pages

TGIF,

I have a website I'm developing which is using ASP.NET masterpage/sitemap/content pages setup. I hate the "blinking" the site does when navigating between content pages using the asp:menu control. Any suggestions on how to use jQuery ajax instead of AJAX.NET updatepanels? I've used updatepanels in the past and I hate it; clunky and bloated.

Here's the code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <link href="styles/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Impeccable Construction Service</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="header">
            <asp:Image ID="HeaderLogo" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/header-logo.png" />
            <asp:Image ID="SubHeader" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/sub-header.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
            <asp:Menu ID="NavMenu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"
                StaticDisplayLevels="2" MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="4" DynamicHorizontalOffset="1"
                StaticSubMenuIndent="1px" DynamicPopOutImageUrl="images/right-arrow.gif" StaticPopOutImageUrl="images/drop-arrow.gif"
                CssClass="NavMenu" Height="30px">
                <StaticMenuItemStyle ItemSpacing="10" CssClass="staticMenuItemStyle" />
                <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="staticHoverStyle" />
                <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="staticMenuItemSelectedStyle" />
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="dynamicMenuItemStyle" />
                <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="menuItemMouseOver" />
                <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="menuItem" />
                <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="menuItemSelected" />
                <DataBindings>
                    <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="siteMapNode" NavigateUrlField="url" TextField="title"
                        ToolTipField="description" />
                </DataBindings>
            </asp:Menu>
            <asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath1" runat="server" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true"
                PathSeparator=" >> " CssClass="currentNodeStyle">
                <PathSeparatorStyle ForeColor="#5D7B9D" CssClass="currentNodeStyle" />
                <CurrentNodeStyle ForeColor="#333333" CssClass="currentNodeStyle" />
                <NodeStyle ForeColor="#7C6F57" CssClass="currentNodeStyle" />
                <RootNodeStyle ForeColor="#5D7B9D" CssClass="currentNodeStyle" />
            </asp:SiteMapPath>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <h4>
                Rivera Design Studio
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929497/loading-gif-in-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your content pages static or dynamic?  If they are static you can always perform a get and swap out the content like so:

```
function GetNewContent(contentSource)
{
  $.get(contentSource, function(content){

     $('#contentArea').html(content);   

  });
}
```

where contentSource is your URL of the content you wish to retrieve.  You could get rid of your Asp menu and go for simple asp:repeater and feed it with your data.

To be honest, the site map is over engineered and pretty inflexible when compared to simple jQuery nav solutions where you build out your menus with ul/ li tags.  It is easier to roll your own data structure and pump it down to the client for jQuery to manipulate.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **[SuperFish plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples)** for jQuery in conjunction with your SiteMap and Menu. Here's a **[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103630/jquery-menu-and-asp-net-sitemap/647656#647656)**.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

```
$.getJSON(myAction, { Data: myData }, function(data) {

 // process data return on callback

});
```